# I to add folder nesting in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

```
I have multiple classes in my C# project
dir1
    -folder1
          -file1.cs
          -file2.cs
    -folder2
    -file3.cs
dir2
   -folder3
         -file.cs
```

How to maintain this folder structure in doxygen also???
Because in Doxygen it is listing all classes under same folder 'Classes'
I have gone through all document but not found anything

Answer (score 0):

Normally the folder structure can be found in the File Reference. See the red frame in this picture:
[image: Doxygen HTML Output: File Reference Page]

Comment: Further, if you are using an older Version like v1.7.x or v1.8.0 then you need to set the SHOW_DIRECTORIES variable in the doxyfile to YES. Then it will show a directory hierarchy in the documentation (if you have documented them with the @dir command). Unfortunately this feature was changed in the newer versions of Doxygen to be shown in the File Reference Pages, so that SHOW_DIRECTORIES and the directory hierarchy documentation became obsolete, so that there is no separate File Hierarchy Page anymore. (I liked the old extra directory hierarchy much more than the new integrated version).

Answer (score 0):

Use the @dir command to document a directory:

```
/**
 * @dir src
 * This is the top level directory of the source files.
 * Here a more detailed description of the directory.
 */
```